# sf::st_read_db() considerably slower than postGIStools::get_postgis_query()

Tags: postgresql, r, sf

I have a large (extent not size) polygon layer of the German federal state borders on my PostgreSQL data base. There is also an index on the geom column.

```
CREATE INDEX germany_bld_geom_idx
  ON spatial_derived.germany_bld
  USING gist
  (geom);
```

Using the sf:: package to load the layer into R takes extremely long ~40s:

```
# bld = sf::st_read_db(con, table = c('spatial_derived', 'germany_bld'))
bld = sf::st_read_db(con, query = "SELECT * FROM spatial_derived.germany_bld", geom_column = 'geom')
```

Using the postGIStools:: package, it is done in ~0.5s:

```
bld = postGIStools::get_postgis_query(con, "SELECT * FROM spatial_derived.germany_bld", geom_name="geom")
bld = sf::st_as_sf(bld)
```

Up to now I've only seen advantages in using sf:: in R, however in this case other packages are faster. Is st_read_db() still in development? What causes this big difference?

Comment: might be worth opening this as a github issue at https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues

Comment: did so: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/503